# Microsoft Access OleDb Connection Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I am trying to access an Access 2003 database remotely from my ASP.NET application. My code is:

```
DataSet dsImportedData = new DataSet();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=MS Remote;Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Remote Server=http://myIp;Data source=C:\myDatabase.mdb;";
try
{
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
  conn.Open();
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command);
  adapter.Fill(dsImportedData);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
  conn.Close();
}
```

However, I am always getting an exception stating: {"[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."}

My command is basic, I have no idea what could be wrong with it. Did anyone confront with the same issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
String command = "SELECT * FROM myTable";

conn.Open();

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, conn);
adapter.Fill(dsImportedData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried it and still get the same error.

Comment: {"[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."}. There's also an error code specified: -2146819841.

Comment: Did you try 
ex: 
`command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;`
`command.CommandText = "myTable";`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error can be caused by the specified table not existing.  Just a thought...

Another thought would be to remove the remoting complexity and try to get to the most simple working code, possibly with a new access database just to start to narrow down what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the command type to Stores procedure it works for me.

```
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```